# How to create a Google-like Calendar with existing components of WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, calendar

I would like to create a calendar, but I don't want to create a new calendar component (btw because I don't know how to). I only would like to use existing components provided by the basic winforms technology (e.g. textbox, picturebox, etc). So, I was wondering what could be the best way to create an easy-to-understand calendar from those components, just like e.g. Google Calendar. It doesn't have to be that complex. It should only be able to handle coincident times. And different background colors for different texts e.g.

I don't require exact answers. Only suggestions is enough. Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion: forget winforms. it's completely useless. use WPF for this. Now comes the close-vote for this `too broad` question.

Comment: I've been learning WPF since then and that's cool! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panels, lots of panels:
7x5 grid (days of the month) 
Headers (days) The location of the days stay the same.
Labeling within the panel.
Labeling for event linked to new form. - you can use the ColorDialog to select text/icon colour (icon: Alt+7 - •)

I'm not sure what you want, but it is possible to do it and make a good looking calender.
You could use picture boxes and simply use paint/paint.net/photoshop/gimp to make the days/grid.

Good luck.

Comment: Except your suggested approach is prone to a lot of `flicker` and will not be resolution independent (at least not with a horrible amount of hacks). And even if the OP makes it thru all the horrible winforms hell, the bitmap-based UI you're suggesting will probably look ugly and pixelated when zoomed in or used in bigger resolutions. My point still stands.

Comment: @HighCore I'm going to prove you wrong with my 'mad art skills', it shall look amazing - google standard.

Comment: yes, please, go ahead and show me a `winforms` based UI that doesn't really suck (without Third Parties such as DevExpress or Infragistics), I'm going to close my StackOverflow account, delete all my answers, quit my job, leave my wife and kid, throw my drumkit to the trash, and become a homeless beggar if you succeed. Don't forget `Resolution Independence` and `Hardware Acceleration`, please. Oh, and Interactivity / "eye candy" features such as `Animations`. Again, no flicker, please.

Comment: and one more thing, please implement your winforms solution using the `MVVM` pattern so that all your application logic is completely decoupled from the UI, in such a way if you later wanted to reuse your logic in other UI frameworks, you wouldn't need to refactor anything, but just change the View layer. And don't forget to create Unit Tests for the ViewModels. Thanks.

Comment: @HighCore You're right, it's going to be hard to make it at any level of quality with just winforms, but I want your wife so I shall continue later.